A question about the use of a phrase about the "successful"
“Be successful to do” or“ be successful in doing something”, which is more standard?

Successful is not complemented by an infinitival clause.

Neither one: To be successful doing something.  To be happy doing something. doing something is a gerund.

@Lambie: Preposition in is more likely to be present than not in references to someone who was successful {in} doing something.

This question should NOT be closed.

Be successful in doing something is fine in my English - especially when it means 'finally manage to do it'.

You simply do not need to say use in.  You can, of course, but there is no grammatical obligation there at all. He was happy working at a bank.

In colloquial American English we often dispense with in in this construction:  The mayor was successful getting City Council to back his tax-abatement plan. OR She was successful having the loans approved.  OR He was successful creating a new account.

@TimR: Your point was already made by Lambie, and imho roundly dismissed by my usage link above.

You will always be more successful doing something you enjoy, that fits with your personality. Prismrecruitment.co.uk Nutrition advice from the UK: 4.  You must feel good/successful doing it (aka Celebrate your success).https://specialistnutritionrehab.co.uk/tiny-habits-big-results-when-changing-behaviour/ I am so tired of reading about uninformed ngrams.

@Lambie "This question should NOT be closed." This question is CV-worthy for all three of our community-specific reasons. It might be answerable with a dictionary search, it shows no effort to have tried to answer the question themselves before asking nor explains anything about what the OP already understands, and the question is arguably structured as a request for proofreading. The lack of research is the solid one.

@gotube Well, I don't think it merited a raking over the coals. And please, can we stop acting like ngrams is some speech god. My point is all this is that it does bring up a very useful point about copular verbs + adjectives and gerund phrases. So, it's a teaching opportunity as they would say in the trade, as it were even though there is lack of research.

@Lambie There's probably a good question in there somewhere, but this question, as is, is not high enough quality for ELL.

@gotube You could at least acknowledge my answer. I really don't understand the ill will of some people here. The question is as I answered it. If a person doesn't know a thing, you provide an answer that clarifies that.

An adjective with  copular verb can easily be followed by a gerund phrase.

He is happy jumping through hoops.
She is "rich" living in poverty.
They are successful designing houses but not apartment blocks.
We were funny making jokes at the event but we aren't being funny now.
You seem unhappy working at that horrible job.
He appeared bored labouring under that illusion.
We always remain calm playing with the dogs.
You seem happy being successful.

One can of course say: He was successful at making money, too. But without at is grammatical too.
To be successful at making money.
To be successful in attempting to climb Everest.

I don't think this is a useful answer. The OP asked about using an infinitive (invalid) or a gerund. You're preoccupied with justifying the gerund form without a preposition - which my link under the question clearly shows is relatively uncommon.

@FumbleFingers But it isn't uncommon at all.  People use those all the the time: He was happy playing in the field. How can you possibly justify a form like that as uncommon? And this: Both have been successful making money by spending money. Forbes

@FumbleFingers And you are doing a disservice to learners as this form is very useful in English. ngrams are not the be-all and end-all of English!

Not my downvote, but "be successful in attempting"  is a non-starter for me. It seems like  a good title for a  pop psychology book:  Successful in Trying: One Step to a Better You

@TimR At this point, all I can say is whatever. Law schools have never
been successful in attempting to climb the summit to have their salaries
or salary increases compared to medicine and denistry.  https://dspace.nku.edu/server/api/core/bitstreams/f6630701-9055-4cb5-84b4-f24e1a3f6707/content Anyway, Incredible. Some professor wrote that many years ago and it's almost like mine.

@Lambie The OP didn't ask about copulas, but about what comes after the adjective "successful". The rule doesn't change if there's a copular verb before it or not.

@gotube That because the OP didn't know about it. As I said, sometimes OPs don't know stuff, so we are here to explain it to them. The rule is about showing this form: Subject [copular verb] [adjective] [gerund phrase]. It seems easy explaining it like this.

@Lambie You don't know whether the OP understands what a copula is because they didn't say anything about that in the question. While that word order is fairly common, it's several structures strung together, not a single underlying structure that answers the question. For instance, the phrase itself can be the subject, and the "be" verb doesn't link anything: "To be successful running a business takes discipline."

@Lambie Further, this is doesn't address the OP's question about [ "successful" + infinitival phrase ] and [ "successful" + prepositional phrases with "in" ]. Instead, your answer improves the phrasing, which is specifically off-topic on this site.

@gotube He is successful running a business and to be successful running a busines takes discipline are the same thing in term of adjective + gerund phrase. That was my main point: You do not need in or at. I addressed it all in my answer. Except for the your infinitive, which, by the way, has the same ending. I do not want to fight anymore about this. I believe this was a teaching opportunity. You don't. So be it. Let's leave it.

@Lambie Again, the OP didn't ask for alternate phrasing. The OP still doesn't know whether the two structures they proposed are correct or not.

Read my answer: I actually addressed it. One can of course say: He was successful at making money, too. But without at is grammatical too.
To be successful at making money. To be successful in attempting to climb Everest.
